# Text next to a frame | Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi so i'm new in Python/Tkinter and i can't find good course or tutorial about this so i'm trying my own thing.
Basically i want to place "Blabla" next to the frame (the white rectangle)

[image: ^^]

but for some reason it doesn't let me place the text at the top left.I have searched on internet,tried to fix it but it still does not work :(

Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.title("Tkinter test")
window.geometry('350x480')
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

window.iconbitmap("test.ico")

window.config(background='#0b0045')

frame = Frame(window, bg='white', width=120, height=220)
frame.pack(pady=25, padx=25, side=TOP, anchor=E)

text1 = Label(window, text="Blabla", font=("Courrier", 30), bg='#0b0045', fg='white')
text1.pack(pady=25, padx=25, side=TOP, anchor=W)

window.mainloop()
```

Any help is appreciated,thanks you bye :D

Comment: Try using: `frame.pack(..., side="right")` and `text1.pack(..., side="left")`.

Comment: "next to" is a bit vague. Next to the frame but aligned to the top? Centered vertically? Should capital "B" be at the left edge of the window, or should lowercase "a" be right up against the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here .pack() is not going to work

again .pack() is not a good geometry manager for designing and hence you should use the .place() geometry manager for more freedom of placing widgets wherever you want....
Here's the link for the .place() tutorial

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/tk_place.htm

Comment: `.place()` geometry manager is really tedious. You need to set the exact place. Though, it allows you to place your widgets in a good fashion, it is much better to use `.grid` for this use case

Comment: I disagree. I would use `.pack` over `.place` in most cases. Each geometry manager has it's own benefits and problems

Comment: *"See here .pack() is not going to work"* is misleading. So I wonder why it is accepted as an answer.

Comment: Because he was right? When i replaced ".pack" with ".place(and some options)" in my code it worked,and did exactly what i wanted to do. Thanks you Prakhar Parikh!

Comment: @acw1668... i said that because the one who asked the question is new to tkinter.... here accepting an answer means that it should work by any means.. I had answered only to help him... my code worked so my answer got accepted

Answer (score 1):

You could put them in a [grid layout](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm) instead, with some padding around the sides.

```
text1 = Label(window, text="Blabla", font=("Courrier", 30), bg='#0b0045', fg='white')
text1 .grid( row = 0,  column = 0, padx = 20,  pady = 20 )

frame = Frame(window, bg='white', width=120, height=220 )
frame .grid( row = 0,  column = 1,  padx = 20,  pady = 20 )
```

[image: Grid Layout]